# Thymeleaf - Manter opção selecionada após executar consulta

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Não estou conseguindo manter a opção selecionada do "select" do Thymeleaf no retorno da consulta. Para o campo texto, incluí `th:value="${cep}"` funcionou, fiz o mesmo para o select, mas não funcionou;

```
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:name="cliente" th:value="${cliente}" id="cliente">
                    <option value="">Selecione o cliente</option>
                    <option
                        th:each="cliente : ${clientes}"
                        th:value="${cliente}" th:text="${cliente.pessoa.nome}">cliente</option>
                </select>
```

Estou retornando cliente para página no model (Controller) `model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);` já confirmei que esse valor está chegando corretamente na página, só falta selecionar esse item no select. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Não escreva resolvido nos títulos das publicações. O simples ato de aceitar uma resposta já informa ao sistema e a comunidade que o problema foi solucionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar `th:selected="condição"`.

Algo como:

```html
<option th:each="c : ${clientes}" th:selected="(${c.id} == ${cliente.id})">cliente</option>
```

Comment: Leandro, funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu pela força.